# can i combine bar and line charts in one chart using fl_chart package flutter

Tags: flutter, charts

I'm using this package fl_chart

can i combine bar and line charts in one chart?

https://pub.dev/packages/fl_chart

This is how i want it to look like[image]

Comment: can you share what type of design you want to achieve?

Comment: I added an image

Comment: This is also what im looking for, did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Any luck finding the answer? Becouse im trying this to in one of my projects

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Add Barchart and Line chart in stack.

```
Stack( children: [ _BarChart(...), _LineChart(...), ], )
```